# Tradução PHP ou JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um uma página, onde devo realizar tradução. A principio havia pensando em traduzir com JS, para fazer algo dinâmico, ou seja, a pessoa iria clicar no botão, eu iria chamar um arquivo .json e realizar a tradução.

Mas depois encontrei a biblioteca `php-gettext`, que realiza o que desejo fazer, mas passando o parâmetro pela URL, como utilizo iframe, complica a alteração manual para o idioma que a pessoa deseja, na situação dada.

Eu testei a biblioteca e ela funciona bem, e o importante que existe o programa poedit que facilita a tradução. Mas tenho um problema, em tempos faço novas atualizações. Dessa forma terei que atualizar o arquivos principal e os demais.

1º -  Existe algum botão no poedit para eu atualizar todo o arquivo .pot, sem perder as funcionalidades já existentes, como também a .po das traduções já realizadas?

> *Verificando o poedit, ele possui uma opção onde posso atualizar o aquivo .po através do .pot atualizado, sem perder as traduções realizadas.

2º - Caso não tenha, qual indicação vocês fariam para que eu consiga traduzir meu site, o que vocês acham da opção com javascript. Acham viável?

3º - Existe alguma maneira mais fácil?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um arquivo .POT pelo próprio Poedit para manter como "catálogo" principal. O legal, é que pelo próprio programa você pode faze-lo vasculhar o código fonte atrás dos novos termos no código-fonte. A partir dai, você pode sempre atualizar seus arquivo .PO a partir do .POT, que ele mantem todas as traduções que você já realizou.

Acredito que essa é uma maneira muito eficiente de fazer a internacionalização de qualquer aplicativo em PHP.

Comment: O bom, que além de atualizar o arquivo .pot... ele atualiza o arquivo .po sem perder as traduções existentes, elas ficam no banco de dados do programa. Meu medo fica em relação a quanto mais de memória, processamento, internet... irá ocupar fazendo este procedimento?